# Can I prevent react components from reloading when changing the query string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using `withRouter()` to add location and history to my react view components. While interacting with the page, I frequently change the query string so that the view can be bookmarked for later viewing. For example, if I click on a country, I might call this code:

```
public onChangeCountry = (countryName: string): void => {
  this.setState({country: countryName});

  const search = `${queryString.stringify({
    country: countryName
  })}`;

  const url = `/countries?${search}`;
  this.props.history.replace(url);
}
```

However, I've noticed some promises throwing "unmounted component" exceptions when I change countries:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the `componentWillUnmount` method.
```

It seems like the component is being unmounted then remounted when the query string changes, which causes the page to fire a fetch() request.

Is there a way to prevent a component from being remounted when just the query string changes?